# transfert large file with wcf service

Tags: wcf

I want to run a WCF service file transfer

my problem is when sending a large file, I get this exception message ProtocolException

> (413) Request Entity Too Large.

this is my configuration

I found this code on the internet, so I'm not sure that it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
            <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
        </system.web>
        <system.serviceModel>
            <behaviors>
                <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior>
                        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                    </behavior>
                </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
            <services>
                <service name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService">
                    <endpoint
                         binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ITransferService"
                         bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService"   />
                </service>
            </services>
            <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" closeTimeout="04:01:00"
                         openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00"
                         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                         maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                         messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8"
                         transferMode="Streamed"
                         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128"
                            maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    </binding>
                </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
        </system.serviceModel>
        <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
            <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: What is the size of file that you want to transfer?

Comment: is dynamic size , it can be image,pdf,word ,xls

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to send a file part by part.

Your API could be sth like this:

```
byte[] GetFile (string FileID, int startByte, int bytes, ...)
```

That way you can easily resume transfer after error, you don't need to worry about timeouts, etc.